# mvc3 actionresult code repeating itself

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Here is a bizarre problem.
I call an ActionResult in my controller from jQuery on a view.

Here is the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.addNoteLink').button();

    $('.addNoteLink').click(function () {
        var cid = $('#CaseID').val();
        var notetext = $('#NoteText').val();
        var url = "/Cases/AddNoteText";
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: { id: cid, note: $('#NoteText').val() }
            });
    });
});
```

Here is the controller method:

```
public ActionResult AddNoteText(int id, string note)
        {
        try
            {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                CaseNotes notes = new CaseNotes
                {
                    CasesID = id,
                    NoteDate = DateTime.Now,
                    NoteText = note
                };
                db.CaseNotes.Add(notes);
                db.SaveChanges();
                }

            }
        catch 
            {

            }
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", id);
        }
```

Here is the html related to the jQuery:

```
<div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.Label("Enter notes here and click Add Note Text")
                </div>
                <div class="textarea-field">
                    <input id = "NoteText" type="text" />
                </div>        
                @Html.ActionLink("Add Note Text", "AddNoteText", new { id = Model.CasesID }, new { @class = "addNoteLink" })
```

When the jQuery calls this method, if I follow with a breakpoint, the parameters are pass correctly, the ModelState is valid, it goes into the notes entity and assigns values etc. When the breakpoint hits db.CasesNotes.Add(notes) the breakpoint returns to the top of the function and goes down again until it hit the notes entity then jumps to db.SaveChanges()
then returns to the top AGAIN, goes thru the method and errors out because the parameters have been cleared by that point. The original record gets inserted though.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I remember something like this. I think it had to do with this name 'id' of `int id` and routing. Need to try to recall

Comment: could you please add the html markup related to the javascript?

Comment: @Jorge, I added the html

Comment: Does this happen when you hit the raw url in your browser?

Comment: Where is your `$('.addNoteLink').click...` function? In the view, in a partial or in a separate file? If in a partial/separate file make sure that it loaded only once.

Comment: jsmith, I am not sure what you mean.
nemesv, the function is in the view, I had set an alert and watched in Firebug to see if it loaded twice.

Comment: @Ryan. I see you have an accepted answer already. I can't recall exactly what problem I had with SaveChanges, but it had to do with the name id clashing with the database (MVC3 + EF). After renaming id to myId in the controlles and the regsiterroutes it worked for me

Comment: @bart s Thanks. I will keep your experience in mind -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you subscribe on an anchor with jQuery click the browser will still execute the default action (e.g follow the link) when you click on the link. That's why your action called twice.

You need call to call the [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) on the event object to cancel the browser default behavior:

```
$('.addNoteLink').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var cid = $('#CaseID').val();
    var notetext = $('#NoteText').val();
    var url = "/Cases/AddNoteText";
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: { id: cid, note: $('#NoteText').val() }
        });
});
```

Comment: thanks for that. It worked great. I dont really see any reason why I should use an Html.ActionLink vs an htm button in this case. Perhaps I will change it to make it easier.